# iOS Delegate is returning nil (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a feeling there is more than one problem with this code, but my first issue is that my delegate returns nil and I do not know why.  First, is my delegate:

```
import UIKit

//delegate to move information to next screen
protocol userEnteredDataDelegate {
func userDidEnterInformation(info:NSArray)
}
```

Next, I have a var defined for the delegate and I believe the ? makes it an optional variable? This is defined inside the class

```
var dataPassDelegate:userEnteredDataDelegate? = nil
```

Now, after my user has entered information into the fields in the view, I want to add those field values to an array and then pass that array on to the next view where it will be added to.  I have pieced this code together from some YouTube examples but I think I am missing a needed part. When do I assign some kind of value to the dataPassDelegate var so it is not nil when the if statement comes? Do I even need that if statement?

```
        if blankData != 1 {
        //add code to pass data to next veiw controller
        enteredDataArray = [enterDate.text, enterSeason.text, enterSport.text, enterDispTo.text]
        //println(enteredDataArray)
        self.appIsWorking ()
        if (dataPassDelegate != nil) {
            let information: NSArray = enteredDataArray
            println(information)
            dataPassDelegate!.userDidEnterInformation(information)
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        } else {
            println ("dataPassDelegate = nil")
        }

        //performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDispenseScreenTwo", sender: self)
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    }
    blankData = 0
}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A delegate is a pointer to another object that conforms to a particular protocol. Often you use delegates to refine the behavior of your class, or to send back status information o the results of an async network request

When you set your `dataPassDelegate` delegate is up to you.

What is the object that has the `dataPassDelegate` property? What object will be serving as the delegate?

You need to create 2 objects (the object that will be serving as the delegate, and the object that has the `dataPassDelegate` property) and link them up.

We can't tell you when to do that because we don't know what you're trying to do or where these objects will be used.

Comment: Duncan, thank you for your reply. I am using a delegate because my google search came up with it when I asked how to move date from one view to another.

My app has 3 views that the user will enter information into fields on. When the user is finished, all the data from all of the fields will be sent up to the cloud and saved. When the user moves from one view to the next, don't I need to move the information with him? Can I just use a global array that I append to as the user moves from view 1 to view 2 and so on?  This is all very new to me so I am at the mercy of how I ask questions.

Comment: ...move "date"? You mean move "data"?

Comment: Googling for terms and then slapping them together without understanding what they are is not going to work. You need to read the Apple Swift iBook, or another introductory book on Swift.

Comment: I am using the books for reference, I am taking classes to learn as well. My challenge is that I learn best when I see things work in a specific way, not in the general ways that are presented in the texts. That is why I am "practicing" my learning by creating projects that will actually do something.

To that end, I search google to help me find some direction when trying to find the best solution to a problem. The books just give the ideas in the abstract. If you have any suggestions for where I can go from here, I appreciate it.